# C++ Object out of scope

Tags: c++, scope

When does the object `Second` go out of scope? If I leave the third cout statement I get a *compiler error*. Even when I surround the initialization of `Second` and the cout statements.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class MyArray{

public:
    int Size;
    int* data;

    MyArray(int s) : Size(s), data(new int[s]){}
    ~MyArray(){
        delete[](this->data);
    }
};



int main()
{

    MyArray First(20);
    First.data[0] = 25;

    MyArray Second = First;
    cout << First.data[0] << endl;
    cout << Second.data[0] << endl;
    cout << Second.data[0] << endl;



    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

The runtime error:
[image]

Comment: A compilation error? Which one?

Comment: Also please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: I wrote this code knowing I need to write a copy constructor. I just wanted to know when `Second` goes out of scope. And why putting curly braces around the third statement doesn't work.
And it is a runtime error. Debug Assertion Failed. Expression: _Block_Type_IS_valid

Comment: @Justin If that was all your question was then why introduce the need for a copy constructor? It's irrelevant to the question of scope.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `delete[](this->data)` is just a long-winded way of writing `delete [] data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what's going on: `MyArray` objects get a pointer to their own array of integers called `data` upon initialization. However, this line changes things for the `Second` object:

```
MyArray Second = First;
```

Now both `First.data` and `Second.data` point to the same `int[]` array, because the default copy constructor and assignment operator perform a *shallow* copy.

This is bad, because the compiler has freedom to destroy `First` after its last use in your code. Hence, accessing `Second.data[0]` may be invalid already.

Moreover, once `First` and `Second` go out of scope at the end of `main()`, they *both* will try deleting `data`. Only the first one would succeed; the second one will trigger undefined behavior.

To avoid such errors in the future, use the [*rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). It says that if you define a destructor, a copy constructor, or an assignment operator, you probably need all three of them.

Your code has only the destructor. Adding a copy constructor and an assignment operator will fix this problem, and prevent memory leaks on assigning `MyArray` objects.

Comment: Thank you, I know I need to add a copy constructor. I'm reviewing some concepts at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of both names ends at the `}`. (Scope is a compile-time notion.)

The lifetime of `Second` ends when execution reaches the end of the block, after which the lifetime of `First` ends. But your program has undefined behaviour because you delete the array twice, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the deep copy using copy constructor

```
MyArray(const MyArray &t)
   {

    t.size = size;
    if(size not_eq 0)
    {
    t.data = new int(size);
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
     t.data[i] = data[i];
    }
   }
```

after this `MyArray Second = First;` will work fine 
if you want to assign then you have to write assignment operator as well